# How i can shorten code for neural-network?

Tags: python, neural-network

I wrote a neural network and after that, i want to write neural network bigger than it, and i dont want to write too big code

```
    input[0] = (player_x - Game_logic.block_1x)

    input[1] = (player_y - Game_logic.block_1y)

    input[2] = (player_x - Game_logic.block_2x)

    input[3] = (player_y - Game_logic.block_2y)

    input[4] = (player_x - Game_logic.block_3x)

    input[5] = (player_y - Game_logic.block_3y)

    

    snk[0] = (((input[0] * weights[0])/10) + ((input[1] * weights[1])/10) + ((input[2] * weights[2])/10) + ((input[3] * weights[3])/10) + ((input[4] * weights[4])/10) + ((input[5] * weights[5])/10) +1)       

    snk[1] = (((input[0] * weights[6])/10) + ((input[1] * weights[7])/10) + ((input[2] * weights[8])/10) + ((input[3] * weights[9])/10) + ((input[4] * weights[10])/10) + ((input[5] * weights[11])/10) +1)     

    snk[2] = (((input[0] * weights[12])/10) + ((input[1] * weights[13])/10) + ((input[2] * weights[14])/10) + ((input[3] * weights[15])/10) + ((input[4] * weights[16])/10) + ((input[5] * weights[17])/10) +1)     

    snk[3] = (((input[0] * weights[18])/10) + ((input[1] * weights[19])/10) + ((input[2] * weights[20])/10) + ((input[3] * weights[21])/10) + ((input[4] * weights[22])/10) + ((input[5] * weights[23])/10) +1) 

    snk[4] = (((input[0] * weights[24])/10) + ((input[1] * weights[25])/10) + ((input[2] * weights[26])/10) + ((input[3] * weights[27])/10) + ((input[4] * weights[28])/10) + ((input[5] * weights[29])/10) +1)

    

    output[0] = ((snake_layer_1[0] * weights[30])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[1] * weights[31])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[2] * weights[32])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[3] * weights[33])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[4] * weights[34])/10)

    output[1] = ((snake_layer_1[0] * weights[35])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[1] * weights[36])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[2] * weights[37])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[3] * weights[38])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[4] * weights[39])/10)

    output[3] = ((snake_layer_1[0] * weights[40])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[1] * weights[41])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[2] * weights[42])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[3] * weights[43])/10) + ((snake_layer_1[4] * weights[44])/10)
```

Comment: You can certainly simplify this with loops.

Comment: Loops, or just use tensorflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, Sergey, actually i don't know how to do it with loops. I mean if i make loops i anyway need to write block_3x or something like it. I just can't invision how to make it with loops, and i need help with it.(sorry, maybe you don't understand me) If you still don't understand me, i try to explain it with deepl translate, or Yandex, or google

Comment: You can use a `dict` or a `list`, or some other dynamic way to store the `block_1y` objects and such, rather than explicitly naming a bunch of them. Also, naming a variable `input` is a bad idea since that causes the built-in `input` function to become inaccessible. Regardless, it seems like you're trying to do something very advanced in Python despite not having advanced knowledge of Python. If you're not sure how to make this into a loop, that's a pretty simple thing to do, so it makes me think you're getting ahead of yourself.

Comment: "Getting ahead of yourself" maybe you are right, i just still learning python, and trying to do something. I need to learn python from start, again i guess

Comment: Also i need more experience how to work with python, 'cuz i just put and use my variables called "block" without any dynamic strogare

Comment: Hi Random Davis, i rewrite code, and want to ask you, what do you think, is it normal code or not?

Comment: ` for choice in range(9):
   circle += 1
   for inp in range(7): 
    snake_layer_1[choice] += (input[inp] * weights[inp+(circle*7)])/(inp+1) `

Comment: This new code i put instead snake layer

Comment: I rewrote code* (sorry my english bad)